# Adding CSP header by merging headers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, http-headers, discourse

I am trying to create a vary basic .rb plugin (based on the now obsolete in chrome) [discourse-allowall](https://github.com/musketyr/discourse-allowall)
 which will merge the CSP header to the default ones but cant get it to work.

The below does not seem to do it.

```
Rails.application.config.action_dispatch.default_headers.merge!({'Content-Security-Policy' => "frame-ancestors 'http://mylocal.com.localhost'"})
```

I literally have 0 experience with ruby so need to know:

1. If thats possible
2. The correct syntax for defining the above header and merging it with the default ones

NOTE: End goal is to allow for the application to be frameable by 2 specific domains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My syntax was off and this is working fine now. Correct syntax is like:

`Rails.application.config.action_dispatch.default_headers.merge!({'Content-Security-Policy' => "frame-ancestors *"})`

Put it up on github in case someone wants to use it as a plugin: https://github.com/mkatrantzis/testDiscourseCSP